# bucle textbox para guardar en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, vb

Estoy trabajando con una BBDD SQL la cual tengo el siguiente formato:

| AlarmaID | TextoAlarma |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Texto1 |
| 2 | Texto2 |
| N.. | TextoN... |
| 16 | Texto16 |

Luego tengo un formulario con 16 textbox con id txtAlarma y al final el numero de la alarma.Por ejemplo txtAlarma4.
Estoy intentando generar un bucle que no me haga crear las 16 sentencias sql.

```
        For i As Integer = 1 To 16
            Dim textBoxName As String = "txtAlarm" & i
            Dim id As Integer = i
            query = "UPDATE ALARMASREF SET TextoAlarma='" & textBoxName.Text & "' where AlarmID='" & i & "'"
        Next
```

También he probado con FindControl y creando un textbox temporal, pero nada no lo consigo.

Como lo podría hacer?

Comment: Hola Brian, ¿podrías indicar el motor de BBDD que estas usando?

Comment: Tienes que usar `FindControl`, coloca la prueba que hiciste para entender porque no te funciona

Comment: @Marcos Estoy utilizando SQL Server 2019. 
@Yussef he hecho varias pruebas con el FindControl, la ultima que probe fue este:

 
`For i As Integer = 1 To 16 Dim textBoxName As String = "txtAlarma" & i Dim textboxTemp As TextBox = FindControl(textBoxName) Dim txtText = textboxTemp.Text query = "UPDATE ALARMASREF SET TextoAlarma='" & prueba & "' where AlarmID='" & i & "'" Next `

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitas: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nDDW.png  ???

Comment: @Yussef He probado con eso y me aparece lo siguiente:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

textboxTemp fue Nothing.

Comment: Puedes colocar una imagen como la que yo he puesto, donde te muestro el aspx y el código ???

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sH0oJpJ ahi esta

Answer (score 0):

Cuando no encuentras un control suele ser causa de una anidación de controles o porque usas un `MasterPage`

Resulta que aspx cambia los `id` en función de un árbol de controles, por ejemplo un textbox con id `txtAlarm1` puede pasar a llamarse `ctl00$MainContent$txtAlarm1`, de esta manera se asegura de tener `id` únicos. Torpemente `FindControl` busca por los id's generados y no por los que están declarados por el desarrollador

*(OJO que esto también te influye cuando usas javascript para modificar el DOM)*

Podrías ir al navegador e inspeccionar elemento y saber que ID te está generando, pero esto no es muy buena idea, porque ante cualquier modificación que realices en la estructura te va a cambiar los ID

La solución simple es convertir un `div` padre en un `asp:Panel`

```
<%--Esto antes era <div class="box-body">--%>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="box-body">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAlarm1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAlarm2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Predictable"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAlarm3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Y luego haces un `FindControl` de lo que está dentro de `Panel1`

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim textboxTemp As TextBox = Panel1.FindControl("txtAlarm" & i)
        Dim query = "UPDATE ALARMASREF SET TextoAlarma='" & textboxTemp.Text & "' where AlarmID='" & i & "'"
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Un último concejo que siempre hago a las personas que utilizan ASPX: No se si este es un proyecto nuevo o viejo. Pero siempre que puedan cambien de tecnología, esta era mala incluso cuando era nueva y ahora además es obsoleta. ASP MVC es la no tan nueva tecnología que deberías usar